# How to derive the logistic regression formula?

Tags: machine-learning

My question is how to derive we can use sigmoid function `1/(1+e^(-w*x))` to map `w*x` to probability space? 
what's the theory behind to prove sigmoid function is optimal method for mapping?
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Wow, new contributor posts a question and gets anonymously downvoted more than 3 times, and without any comments from the downvoters. At times, it looks like math.SE is really full of sh*t. People should really relax!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of sigmoid function is not to "map $w^*x$ to probability space", it is to simulate threshold behaviour for the activation of perceptrons. It is a nice function $\sigma : \mathbb{R}^{length(w)}\mapsto [0 , 1]^{length(w)}$.

But those occurrences of the interval $[0 , 1]$ aren't meaningful probability spaces, they are just activation range of some perceptrons.